# Splitting pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string column that I wish to split into three columns depending on the string. The column looks like this

```
full_string
x a b c
d e
m n o
y m n
y d e f
d e f
```

`x` and `y` are prefixes. I want to convert this column into three columns

```
prefix_string  first_string last_string
x              a            c
               d            e
               m            o
y              m            n
y              d            f
               d            f
```

I have this code

```
df['first_string'] = df[df['full_string'].str.split().str.len() == 2]['full_string'].str.split().str[0] 
df['first_string'] = df[df['full_string'].str.split().str.len() > 2]['full_string'].str.split().str[1]

df['last_string'] = df['full_string'].str.split().str[-1]

prefix_string = ['x', 'y'] 
df['prefix_string'] = df[df['full_string'].str.split().str[0].isin(prefix_string)]['full_string'].str.split().str[0]
```

This code isn't working correctly for `first_string`. Is there a way to extract the `first string` irrespective of `prefix_string` and the string length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of these lines in your Above code:

```
df['first_string'] = df[df['full_string'].str.split().str.len() == 2]['full_string'].str.split().str[0] 
df['first_string'] = df[df['full_string'].str.split().str.len() > 2]['full_string'].str.split().str[1]
```

make use of `split()`,`contains()` and `fillna()` method:

```
df['first_string']=df['full_string'].str.split(expand=True).loc[~df['full_string'].str.split(expand=True)[0].str.contains('x|y'),0]
df['first_string']=df['first_string'].fillna(df['full_string'].str.split(expand=True)[1])
```

Output of `df`:

```
    full_string     first_string    last_string     prefix_string
0   x a b c             a               c                   x
1   d e                 d               e                   NaN
2   m n o               m               o                   NaN
3   y m n               m               n                   y
4   y d e f             d               f                   y
5   d e f               d               f                   NaN
```

Comment: Updated my answer...Kindly have a look

Answer (score 1):

Try with `numpy.where` and `pandas.Series.str.split`:

```py
import numpy as np

prefix_str = ["x", "y"]

res = df["full_string"].str.split(" ", expand=True).ffill(axis=1)
res["last_string"] = res.iloc[:, -1]
res["prefix_string"] = np.where(res[0].isin(prefix_str), res[0], "")
res["first_string"] = np.where(res["prefix_string"].ne(""), res[1], res[0])

res = res[["prefix_string", "first_string", "last_string"]]
```

Outputs:

```py
  prefix_string first_string last_string
0             x            a           c
1                          d           e
2                          m           o
3             y            m           n
4             y            d           f
5                          d           f
```